# Broken url in Yii application

Tags: php, yii

My web Yii application is in /var/www/ in my Ubuntu server. When I try to change the main config file:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
    ),
```

To hide the index.php file, it said: The requested URL was not found on this server(404 error). The .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

And still is not working correct.

Later edit: The solution is to put "AllowOverride All" in Directory tag /var/www/ on the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default alongside with mod rewrite

Comment: "Broken" how? How does it not work correctly? What do the URLs look like and what happens when you try to access them?

Answer (score 0):

I have this rules in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

try them, remeber that you need to turn on the Mod_rewrite in you Apache server.